# Creating PHP file to check if other file exists (from PHP file)

Tags: php

Yes, I know my title is a bit confusing.
Anyway, I have a PHP file, which I want to drop another PHP file, and the dropped PHP file would check if the creator exists, and if it doesn't it deletes files, how could I do this? I know how to drop a text file with some content in it, but not a much more complicated PHP file with multiple lines.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Not only your title is confusing to me. Could you give an example of what you are trying to do? And clarify what "drop" means in this context?

Comment: Clearly confusing by htis line "the dropped PHP file would check if the creator exists" ---- what it mean "if the creator exists, and if it doesn't it deletes files"

Comment: @simon drop = create | I want the created php file to check if the creator still exists, and if it doesn't, it does an action (e.g delete files)

Comment: I see. Parziphals answer does exactly what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that with "drop" you mean "create", this would work:

File `parent.php`:

```
<?php

// Child destination
$childFile = __DIR__ . '/child.php';

// Full path to this parent file
$file      = __FILE__;

// Child contents
$contents = <<<EOT
<?php

if (!is_file('${file}')) {
    // Parent doesn't exist; delete some files and exit
    // unlink(...);
    exit;
}

// Parent exists; keep doing something else
echo "I'm the child!";

EOT;

// Create child file
file_put_contents($childFile, $contents);

// Do something else...
echo "Created child";
```

The parent creates a child file, where the existance of the parent is checked; if it doesn't exist, the child will do something else and then exit.